# Is Hyperledger Composer mandatory to setup a Multi-Node Multi Org Hyperledger fabric network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am getting started with the Hyperledger fabric network. I went through the examples of setting up single org setup on a single node and Single Org-Multi Node as well. 
I am now trying to setup a Multi-Org, Multi Node network and the all the examples I have seen online, uses Hyperledger Composer. So, Is Composer mandatory to setup HYL-Fabric Multi-node, Multi-Org structrure, If not, can anyone provide me with the steps needed to setup a n/w without the composer?

Thanks

Comment: no, not mandatory . Sure -  for 'the steps needed to set up a network' with Hyperledger Fabric - you just go to the Fabric docs site - eg https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/build_network.html - this tutorial may also give you more [insights](https://medium.com/@mycoralhealth/start-your-own-hyperledger-blockchain-the-easy-way-5758cb4ed2d1)

Comment: Thanks for your response, Paul. I did go through the 1.2 release example and it talks only about the 2 org setup on a single node - Not a multi node setup. When we talk about multiple nodes, there are other components like the swarm/Kubernets etc that has to play a ole as well, right?